# Which Cricut cuts wood?

Tags: wood, cutting-machine

I have a Cricut Explore Air and do not believe it can cut thin wood. But then again, this is why I am asking the question. Are there certain Cricuts that can or can not cut wood?

Comment: My first reaction to the question was doesn't the Cricut web site list that? But they seem to go to great lengths to obfuscate exactly what kinds of materials each model can and cannot cut. I managed to find some links covering the Maker series, but nothing definitive for other models. Elmy's link is better than anything I found. The maker series is apparently more powerful, and I think I saw that those models can cut wood slightly thicker (a little over 2 mm if I remember).

Answer (score 9):

According to this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/RIqPFAnzrZg) only the Cricut Maker and Explorer are able to cut wood and only very thin wood of 1/16th of an inch or 1.5 mm or thinner. You also need to use very soft wood like Balsa or Bass. Since wood veneers are even thinner than wood sheets, you can cut these as well and even veneer of harder wood types.

You cannot cut any plywood, even if it's thin enough.

You need:

- a deep cut blade or knife blade
- a strong grip cutting mat (the purple one)
- painters tape to additionally secure the wood on the adhesive mat

Depending on your material (wood or veneer) you also have to set your machine to cut in several passes. More details and the cut settings can be seen in the video linked above.

Answer (score 5):

Cricut cutting machines that can cut wood:

- **Cricut Maker:** This machine can cut a variety of materials, including balsa wood, basswood, and chipboard, up to 2.4 mm thick.
- **Cricut Explore Air:** This machine can cut balsa wood and basswood up to 1.5 mm thick, as well as chipboard, matboard, and foam board up to 2 mm thick.
- **Cricut Joy:** This machine is specifically designed for cutting lightweight materials such as paper, vinyl, and cardstock, but it can also cut balsa wood and basswood up to 1.5 mm thick.

Note that you will need to use the appropriate blade and settings for each type of wood. You can find more detailed information about cutting wood with Cricut machines in the user manual or on the Cricut website.

For more information, see the Cricut article "[Cricut Maker: Cutting balsa wood with Knife Blade](https://help.cricut.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009556693-Cricut-Maker-Cutting-balsa-wood-with-Knife-Blade)".